# Updating a mysql column to NULL through PHP is not working

Tags: php, mysql

When i click this button my page is forwarded to a removeRowValue.php page:

```
<a href="/includes/incl/removeRowValue.php?name=ontvangenklantdatum"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Empty</button></a>
```

My removeRowValue.php page:

```
<?php
session_start();
$str = (int) $_SESSION['rights'];
$accptList = array(1,3);
if(!in_array($str, $accptList)){          
    header('Location: index.php?pagina=login');
}
    require('conn.inc.php');
    $getName        = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "name", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $columnName     = 'rd_' . $getName;
    $artCode        = $_SESSION['artcode'];
    $getadmrmaid    = $_SESSION['getadmrmaid'];

    $delRmaDetVal = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE rma_detail LEFT JOIN rma ON rma_detail.rd_rma_id=rma.r_id SET $columnName = NULL WHERE rd_artikel_code = :artcode AND r_nr = :getadmrmaid");
    $delRmaDetVal->bindParam(':artcode', $artcode, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $delRmaDetVal->bindParam(':getadmrmaid', $getadmrmaid, PDO::PARAM_INT);   
    $delRmaDetVal->execute();

?>
```

- In my mysql table empty is checked for that column
- Default value is NULL.

I have updated the NULL to some value (ie: 2014-12-2) but now i want to put it back to NULL when i click the above button but this is not working. I don't get any error.

Comment: does your column(s) allow null? :D

Comment: Can you echo the query?

Comment: Out of scope of the question, but from what I can remember from my PHP days, your security check is broken.  You set a header to redirect to the login page if `$_SESSION['rights']` doesn't include the required `$accptList`, but you don't exit the script or wrap the rest in an `else`, so the database code executes even if the header is sent, doesn't it?

Comment: @DanFarrell That makes a lot of sense. Mind if I quote you in my answer?

Comment: Not at all, please do

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have

```
$artCode = $_SESSION['artcode'];
```

yet are using `$artcode` in your bind. Notice the lowercase "c".

Variables are case-sensitive. Therefore, you need to change it to `$artCode`

Using [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) would have signaled an undefined variable.

Add `$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` right after the connection is opened.

- You may not be checking for errors.

Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.

---

Quoting Dan Farrell in comments:

*"Out of scope of the question, but from what I can remember from my PHP days, your security check is broken. You set a header to redirect to the login page if `$_SESSION['rights']` doesn't include the required `$accptList`, but you don't exit the script or wrap the rest in an `else`, so the database code executes even if the header is sent, doesn't it?"*

- You should also add an `exit;` after your header. If it exits to the header, then you will know that it's the first part of your code that is failing.
- `exit;` should always be following a header, and is considered good practice to do so.

---

I also suggest you check whether or not all of the session names are indeed set using `isset()` and maybe even if they are empty using `empty()` in a conditional statement.

I.e.:

```
if( isset($_SESSION['artcode']) && !empty($_SESSION['artcode']) )
```

While adding other session variables to that condition, and checking to see if your column does allow NULL, as mentioned in comments.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help in this. I am very glad that it works now and sometimes it is not the code but just a stupid fault. Tha camelcase writing had done the trick!

Comment: @DanFarrel & Fred I did not knew that before you guys actually have brought something new to me! Thank you for that. Sadly i cannot give you both a +1 because my reputation is still not growing fast but nice work!

Comment: @Peter You're very much welcome Peter. Glad to have helped and sharing the wealth ;) *Cheers*